# Visual Studio 2013: Is there a way to set properties like Autosize to true for all Forms on a particular project?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm just curious if there is an easy way to set a WinForm property like Autosize (for example) to true for every form in a project without having to manually change every single one of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Form called BaseForm and let all other forms inherit from it. On the BaseForm you can set the desired font, scaling etc. and all other forms will inherit these properties. This is the first thing I do in every Windows Forms project I fire up.

You may also consider creating a BaseDialog, inheriting from BaseForm. This BaseDialog can have hidden minimize/maximize buttons etc. that you would like to be common for all modal dialogs in your application.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but this particular piece of software already has all the forms created and in a working form. The issue was that the buttons weren't lining up when the Windows font size was set to 125%. Therefore, creating a new form and making all the forms inherit from that would be even more work at this point in the software's lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure from your question whether this will meet your needs but the Application.OpenForms property allows you to enumerate all open Form instances: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.90).aspx